# Missing Network Credentials : Windows Sharing

Tags: file-sharing, window

I have created a homegroup and I have 5 computers connected.
However, "sometimes" one of the computers cannot access another computer's shared folder or even the computer. It is asking for Security Credentials which I believe I haven't set it up or reconfigure.

4 of the computers are running on Windows 8.1 and one is Windows 7.
The computers having the problem have the same operating system which is Windows 8.1.

I already change the homegroups and even change the usernames of both PC.
And sometimes, yes, there is no problem at all, and sometimes like now, it is again having problem.

I cannot barely explain why this happened.

Comment: I've been taught that these "Home Groups" cause significant challenge for people who are very familiar with the more traditional file sharing methods.  If I were designing this whole network, I would likely have all systems leave the home groups.  Then get file sharing to be functional, which may require using some credentials (username / password)